# Using 2 concat statements to make 1 table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation

```
select concat(mem_fname, mem_lname) as 'Membership Name'
from membership;

select concat (mem_street, mem_city, mem_state, mem_zip) as 'Membership Address'
from membership;
```

I am trying to make these 2 concat statements make 1 single table.  The table should be like this:

Membership name and membership address are the fields with the correct data below them (tried to make a table in this but it is not letting me).

Now each of these work if I just use 1 concat statement, so I know that they are working and giving me the output that I am looking for but I do not know how to put them into 1 single table.  If you want to see the full data for the tables I am looking to make I can post it.

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
select concat(mem_fname, mem_lname) as Name,
       concat (mem_street, mem_city, mem_state, mem_zip) as Address
  from membership;
```

Comment: And it should allow the quoted aliases with the blanks in the names too.

Comment: yes it is, guess i needed to add a space for the second concat